# Site/service for testing Excel compatibility

Tags: microsoft-excel, compatibility, xml

We distribute an Excel 2003 compatible XML file that users can fill out and resubmit on the site. While the Excel compatible XML file works fine with Office 2003 and Office 2007, with Office 2010 (14.0.4760.1000), it gives an error "The file is corrupt and cannot be opened."

(a) are there services which allow me to test my files on different Excel versions?

(b) what could possibly be causing this problem in Excel?